# Getting rid of unallowed characters in filename

Tags: c, windows, file, filenames

I am working on a small application that recieves a path and a file name and creates a file accordingly.
I have realized that some characters are not allowed in winapi filenames (for example a colon, a dot, etc). Therefore I want to get rid of them as soon as I recieve the filename from the client. 
I was wondering if there is a c function that does that for me. So far, the internet brought up nothing.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What algorithm do you want to use? For example, what happens if the user supplies this file name: `.` or this one `/`, or this one `:`? Incidentally, `.` is not an invalid character in any modern file system that I know of.

Answer (score 4):

Different file systems have different rules for what characters are valid and what isn't. That is why there isn't a general solution.

The best option is to try and create the file, and if it fails, reject it.

Otherwise you will need research all the limitations, and hand code one:

- [General Windows Naming Restrictions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247)
- [FAT vs NTFS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/100108)

Answer (score 0):

You could do a foreach loop and check if it Contains an unallowed character and thenreplace it with something else. You could use the .Substring(number, number) for that.

Im sorry for not giving you an actual code snippet, but i am not with my computer right now

You can look up the .Substring at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx

Hope it helps!

I found the replace method and the contains method to work fine, code below

```
string someword = "Thisisastring...";
        someword = someword.ToLower();
        Console.WriteLine(someword);
        if (someword.Contains("."))
        {
          someword = someword.Replace(".", "(dot)").ToString();
        }
        if (someword.Contains("t"))
        {
            someword = someword.Replace("t", "tee").ToString();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(someword);
```

I hope this was about what you wanted.